# Conditional summing in FileMaker Pro 14

Tags: sum, conditional-statements, filemaker

I want to know how do you get conditional sums on FM 14, because I can´t find anything.

I have X number of records in a layout. Each record has Price, Name and Month. I want to create another layout in which I will have a table with the months arranged horizontally and Name arranged Vertically. Like this:

```
       January    February    March    April     ....    ....   ....  December
```

Name 1     (calc)

Name 2     (calc)

Name 3     (calc)

....

....

....

Name X

---

(calc) = Calculation

I want to sum every price on each record that has the Name and Month specified in each calculation.

I can´t find the way to do it and it´s driving me crazy.

Thanks

Comment: I posted my answer, similar to Michael's. One thing you have to remember: you will need to isolate the year of the record.

Comment: @FrnandoSalazar Do your records not have a Date field?

Answer (score 0):

Filemaker is not very good at cross-tab reports, Still, here's one way to look at it:

Define a calculation field `cSplitByMonth` (result is Number, Number of repetitions: 12) =

```
Let ( [
monthNames = "January¶February¶March¶April¶May¶June¶July¶August¶September¶October¶November¶December" ;
monthName = GetValue ( monthNames ; Get ( CalculationRepetitionNumber ) )
] ;
If ( Extend ( Month )  = monthName ; Extend ( Price ) )
)
```

Define a summary field as Total of `cSplitByMonth`, summarize repetitions individually.

Create a layout with a sub-summary part (when sorted by name) and no body part. Place the Name field and the summary field (with all its 12 repetitions, oriented horizontally) in this part.

Sort the records by Name.

---

Another approach can be seen here: http://fmforums.com/topic/71836-getting-more-out-of-filtered-portals-in-version-11/#comment-339728

Answer (score 0):

1. Create 12 calculation fields with formula:

   **If( myTable::Month = 'January'; myTable::Price ; "" )**

   (repeat for every month)
2. Create a list layout based on the same table, with header and footer
3. Add sub-summary when sorted by Name
4. Add to sub-summary Name field
5. Create a summary fields for every earlier created calculation fields based on Sum()
6. Add these summary fields to sub-summary layout part
7. Delete Body layout part
8. Sort records by Name